# Python: How to print from flask to console

Tags: python, facebook, flask

I am working on a facebook chatbot. I know there are some post for the similar question, but I cannot get it works.

Below is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from flask import Flask, request, app

API_ROOT = '/webhook'
app = Flask(__name__)

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

@app.route(API_ROOT, methods=['POST'])
def fb_receive_message():
    eprint('message received')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eprint('Hello world!')
    app.run(host='XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',debug=True,port=XXX)
```

Outcome:

```
Hello world!
 * Restarting with stat
```

when I try with "post" then it does not print anything

Comment: What do you even want to happen?

Comment: what if you set your API_ROOT = '/webhook/' (with trailing slash) ?
or try 'GET' method instead of 'POST' first?

Comment: @HarlyH. Shouldn't need the trailing slash but I agree that he should try 'GET' first since it looks like his problem is not in the code he posted.

Comment: Actually, the post is success and i got auto reply message on facebook(I didn't include the code on the reply). But I want to print some debug message on the console as I need to write more code to handle the reply. No debug message is a pain.

Comment: @John, of course it shouldn't. I was just proposing this in case his POST request doesn't match API_ROOT. I remember when I first started out with Flask this was one of the first problems I ran into. Luckily I was able to quickly fix it without any external help :)

Comment: well, I found that this problem only happen on I run my python on python IDLE, if I run it on windows command prompt, the normal print works too